# PCHIP armadillo function

Tags: c++, matlab, interpolation, armadillo

I am trying to convert some MATLAB code to C++ using armadillo and one of the MATLAB functions used is interp1. "Easy enough", I though, Armadillo has interp1. "linear should be good enough", well I was wrong. So I searched for interp1.m source code and found the Octave source, it uses pchip.m which I found the octave source code but pchip.m uses pchip_deriv.cc which then seems to use a fortran fcn.

So before I start really diving in to the conversion of pchip are there any other libraries or sources that include pchip out there that I could possibly use?

Comment: **Numerical Recipes in C++** by Press, Teukolsky, Vetterling and Flannery...?

Comment: You could implement it manually, would be short enough to fit in a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ever needs this I looked [here](https://www.cs.usask.ca/%7Espiteri/M211/notes/chapter3.pdf) to find the equations. For large data sets it does not seem to work properly so using the matrix formula, I create a sliding window PCHIP interp. Still did not match MATLABs so I average with a linear interp and it's pretty close. Is it the right way to do this? probably not... does it work? Yup!

```
void pchip_slide(const arma::vec& x, const arma::vec& y, const arma::vec& x_new, arma::vec& y_custom,const int M=4){
vec y_interp=zeros<vec>(size(x_new));
interp1(x,y,x_new,y_interp);
int I=0;
int start_interp=0;
int end_interp=0;
for(int ii=0;ii<x_new.n_elem;ii++){
    
    I=index_min(abs(x-x_new(ii)));
    start_interp=std::max((I-2),0);
    end_interp=std::min((start_interp+M-1),int(numel(x)-1));
    
    vec x_mini=x(span(start_interp,end_interp));
    vec y_mini=y(span(start_interp,end_interp));
    mat x_mat=ones<mat>(x_mini.n_elem,x_mini.n_elem);
    for(int ll=0;ll<x_mini.n_elem-1;ll++){
        x_mat.row(ll)=pow((x_mini.t()),(x_mini.n_elem-ll));
    }
    vec c_mini=solve( x_mat, y_mini,solve_opts::fast + solve_opts::no_approx);
    rowvec x_pchip_mini=ones<rowvec>(x_mini.n_elem);
    for (int ll=0;ll<x_mini.n_elem-1;ll++){
        x_pchip_mini(ll)=pow((x_new(ii)),(x_mini.n_elem-ll));
    }
    y_custom(ii)=conv_to<double>::from(x_pchip_mini*c_mini);
    if ((x_new(ii)>=x(0))&& (x_new(ii)<=x(x.n_elem-1))){
        y_custom(ii)=(y_custom(ii)*1/M+y_interp(ii)*3/M);
    }
}
return;
}
```